# Can I generate the number of business days in a month in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, expression

I have a report that takes sales data from a few tables. I want to add a field that will divide the total sales for the given month by the total number of business days in that same month. Is there a way I can calculate that in an expression? Do I need to create a new table in the database specifically for months and their number of business days? How should I go about this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where is your code?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I'm not asking you to write the code for me. I asking for a suggestion about how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I would say that you need a simple function and a table.

The table is to host the **exceptions** like Independence day, labor day, etc.

The function will get two parameters: Month and Year (I'm not providing any sample code since you haven't specified which language you are using).

It will then build a date as yyyy-mm-01 (meaning, first day of the month). If will then loop from 2 to 31 and:

1. Create a new date by adding the index of the loop to the initial date,
2. Check if the resulting date is still within the month,
3. Check if it is a working or not working day (e.g. Sunday),
4. Check if it is found within the table of exceptions.

If the created date passes all the above tests, you add 1 to the counter.

Though it might look complex, it is not and it will provide you the correct answer regardless of the month (e.g. Feb.) and the year (leap or not).

Comment: Thank you for the response. The report is based off an SQL query, and I was planning on using an expression within Microsoft Visual Studio to calculate the Sales by the number of days in the month. Yes, it does seem a bit complex for where I am at, but I will look into trying to create this.

Comment: As stated, it **looks** complex but be sure that you can accomplish that in less than 10 minutes. Just google for the specific functions you need (e.g. which function in your language returns you the name of the day for a given date). Once you got your code furnished, you can post it and an edit to your question and I'll get a look.